# How to get a less specific Locale in Java

Tags: java, locale

Suppose I have `Locale enUS = new Locale("en", "US");`. Is there a way to extract the language locale from it, better/nicer than `Locale en = new Locale(enUS.getLanguage());` ?

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't find the above too verbose myself commons.lang's `LocaleUtils` may look cleaner:

```
LocaleUtils.toLocale(enUS.getLanguage());
```